# How can I get control functionalities in the notification center like in Android?

Tags: ios

How can I get control functionalities in the notification center like in Android?

I would like to be able to turn Bluetooth on and off without going though layers of menu in the Settings.app.

Is this possible?  And if it is, how do you do it?

Answer (score 3):

No, this isn't possible. On iOS devices, the only way is via the Settings, unfortunately - at least, on a non-jail-broken device.